# Why is this number not working in a php if-statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I defined a variable called `$thumbs_number.`

I did `var_dump`:

```
string(52) "2"
```

and `print_r`

```
2
```

It looks like `$thumbs_number` is 2 right now.
But then I do this:

```
<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 2 ) : ?>
    <span><?php _e( 'two likes' ); ?></span>
<?php else : ?>
    <span><?php _e( 'likes' ); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm still getting 'likes' not 'two likes'

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

here is the variable comming from:

```
<?php $thumbs_number = wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs($template_id = 46, $read_only = false, $stars_set = "", $stars_size = 0, $stars_set_ie6 = "", $echo = false); ?
```

Comment: `string(52)` says that it's not only `"2"`. Where does this string come from?

Comment: The comment above (deceze) hints into the right direction; the string contains more than just the 2, so the comparison must fail. Btw - what kind of strange function call is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/gd-star-rating/tags/1.9.9/code/fn/legacy.php says "@return string html with rendered contents" in the docs. It is probably not just returning the number, or whitespace along with it, but html-tags (you can check this by using 'view source' on the output result. If you just view it in the browser, it will parse the html-tags and you won't see them.)

A simple trim isn't enough. (Besides, php can autoconvert the string with spaces to a number.) Either check for a more appropriate wordpress function that gives it back number you want without html, or use a regexp / substring to extract the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumbs_number = trim(wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs($template_id = 46, $read_only = false, $stars_set = "", $stars_size = 0, $stars_set_ie6 = "", $echo = false));
```

Trim the whitespace and it should compare correctly.